# Locating Notepad++ Configuration files

Tags: notepad++, configuration-files

I am running Notepad++ (NPP) v6.3.3 on Windows 7 and am trying to find the location of my NPP 'Style Configurator' and 'Preferences' files (to sync across my home and work computers).

I checked other postings on how to accomplish this, but the configuration file is not in my 'C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\' folder. In fact, there is no '~\Roaming\Notepad++' folder.

When I make changes to my styles and preferences, the changes are saved (somewhere) if I close and reopen NPP. Any suggestions on where I can find the configuration file?

Comment: That means you don't have a Roaming profile.  Have a look for the ~\Local\Notepad++ or ~\LocalLow\Notepad++ directories.

Comment: That is where the file is located. Thank you.